# XSD for repeat elements with same name but different attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, repeat

I am trying to write a XSD for the following XML snippet.

```
<loop id="1000" name="loop 1000" />
<loop id="1000" name="loop 1000" />
<loop id="2000" name="loop 2000" />
<loop id="2000" name="loop 2000" />
<loop id="2000" name="loop 2000" />
```

I wrote the following XSD

```
<xs:element name="loop" maxOccurs="3">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="1000" type="xs:string" name="id" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="loop" maxOccurs="3">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="2000" type="xs:string" name="id" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But this seems to be failing in XML validation.

The XML is not in my control. How do I handle this?

**EDIT:**

I wrote a xml parser+generator and changed the received XML to something like

```
<_1000>...</_1000>
<_1000>...</_1000>
<_2000>...</_2000>
<_2000>...</_2000>
<_2000>...</_2000>
```

Now I can write the XSD easily for this.

Comment: You mentioned unique attribute value, but I see its repeated.

Comment: By unique I mean distinguish on different attrib values. So 1000 and 2000 are 2 different values

Answer (score 1):

```
<xs:element name="loop" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="1000" type="xs:string" name="id" />
                <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="loop 1000" type="xs:string" name="name" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="loop" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="2000" type="xs:string" name="id" />
                <xs:attribute use="required" fixed="loop 2000" type="xs:string" name="name" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

Comment: Hi Swati, the XML posted is just a snippet of the complete XML. What I need to achieve is mentioned in the XSD that I have tried. loop with id 1000 can repeat 3 times, followed by loop with id 2000 for 3 times. I feel your xsd won't validate that exactly.

Comment: Ok. Then code inside '<xs:element name="test">' should be useful to you. Try it out.

Comment: This won't work. The problem is, it tries to match second 1000 loop with the second <xs:element name="loop" and hence reports 1000 does not match 2000 value for attrib id

Comment: I wrote a xml parser+generator and changed the received XML to something like `<_1000>...</_1000><_1000>...</_1000><_2000>...</_2000><_2000>...</_2000><_2000>...</_2000>`. Now I can write the XSD easily for this.